# center align images after doing a crossdisolve

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have series of images i fade in out over each other
but my problem is the images very in size and layout is a responsive design

my problem

1. keep footer in correct position in document flow
2. center images in containing div

here is the basic idea

```
<div class=“imagecontainer”>
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
</div>
<divclass=“footer”>this jumps up and down when do a cross dissolve since i have to use absolute positioning </div>
```

Comment: set width/height for images and use postion:absolute to footer

Comment: no that won't work i need to keep images responsive

Comment: Loop over the images with jQuery (after they are all finished loading), get their effective heights and from that the maximum height – and set that as height for the container …

Comment: @CBroe this is what I would also suggest. I have implemented this approach many times.